# Loading trained Model in customize R package

Tags: r

I am currently building a R package and I want to use a trained model in one of my R script. Is it possible to load the model (saved in .rds form)?

Comment: Try `usethis::use_data()` to create package data and objects.

Comment: @DarrenTsai There are multiple models that I want to use. So it requires me to use `overwrite = TRUE` :(

Comment: `overwrite` controls whether existing files are overwritten or not. I think you don't have existing files, so not setting it is ok. Try `usethis::use_data(model1, model2, ..., internal = T)`.

Comment: Then load your developing package again by `devtools::load_all(".")`, `model1`, `model2`, ... can be used in any script.

Comment: @DarrenTsai thanks! This works, just a bit inconvenient to load everything all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly the way you described it. Save object with saveRDS function and load it with readRDS. You have to remember to load every package you used for the model, and to prepare data in exact way for prediction.

Comment: where should I save my models?

Comment: Hey, you can add it simply as "data" part in your package. After build it will be accessible for all your function inside package.